# install cocoapods failed on mac

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rake, cocoapods

I tried to install cocoapods on mac according to the instructions http://cocoapods.org/ , but got the error as below:

```
$sudo gem install cocoapods

ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
bad response Service Unavailable: Back-end server is at capacity 503       (https://api.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=cocoapods)
```

but sometimes, the error message is different。

```
$ sudo gem install cocoapods
Password:
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing cocoapods:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

rake RUBYARCHDIR=/Users/tap4fun/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/extensions/x86_64-darwin-12/1.9.1/xcodeproj-0.17.0 RUBYLIBDIR=/Users/tap4fun/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/extensions/x86_64-darwin-12/1.9.1/xcodeproj-0.17.0/Users/tap4fun/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:298:in `to_specs': Could not find 'rake' (>= 0) among 20 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
from /Users/tap4fun/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:309:in `to_spec'
from /Users/tap4fun/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:53:in `gem'
from /Users/tap4fun/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/bin/rake:22:in `<main>'
from /Users/tap4fun/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
from /Users/tap4fun/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'

rake failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/tap4fun/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3- p484/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/xcodeproj-0.17.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/tap4fun/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/extensions/x86_64-darwin-12/1.9.1/xcodeproj-0.17.0/gem_make.out
```

ruby version: 1.9.3

rake version: 10.2.2

Comment: Are you on OSX Yosemite?

Comment: yes, the version is 10.9.3

Comment: The above method also works on latest MacOS Beta and Xcode Beta, just incase anyone was interested...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this (Worked for me with OSX 10.10)

1. Open Xcode 6
2. Open Preferences
3. Click the Locations tab
4. Change the Command Line Tools version to Xcode 6.0
5. Uninstall cocoapods

   $ sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
6. Install xcodeproj

   $ sudo gem install xcodeproj
7. Install cocoapods

   $ sudo gem install cocoapods

Run `pod --version` to verify

Comment: it doesn't work, ERROR:  Error installing xcodeproj:ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension./Users/tap4fun/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:298:in `to_specs': Could not find 'rake' (>= 0) among 20 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)

Comment: Ok you have the same problem I had... so first enter this into terminal: ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install)"

Comment: then what should I do?

Comment: $ brew install postgresql

Comment: I meet the error when install the postgresql, Error: Homebrew doesn't know what compiler versions ship with your version
of Xcode (6.0). Please `brew update` and if that doesn't help, file
an issue with the output of `brew --config`:
  https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues

Note that we only track stable, released versions of Xcode.

Comment: $ brew --config
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 0.9.5
ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew.git
HEAD: fd7e59888a1fa9614e08d2712618ffce526d9ce3
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /Users/tap4fun/.rvm
HOMEBREW_CELLAR: /Users/tap4fun/homebrew/Cellar
CPU: quad-core 64-bit sandybridge
OS X: 10.9.3-x86_64
Xcode: 6.0 => /Applications/Xcode6-Beta.app/Contents/Developer
Clang: 6.0 build 600
X11: N/A
System Ruby: 2.0.0-451
Perl: /usr/bin/perl
Python: /usr/bin/python
Ruby: /Users/tap4fun/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/bin/ruby

Comment: Exactly what is displayed. .. it says brew update so first type:brew doctor hit enter then after that type brew update

Comment: sorry for he later response. postgresql is installation successfully.But Install xcodeproj always failed, the error message same as my first comment.

Comment: haha, i am success, there are something wrong with my development environment ,so i followed the instruction from the [link](http://www.moncefbelyamani.com/how-to-install-xcode-homebrew-git-rvm-ruby-on-mac/) and reinstalled the CLT, homebrew and rvm, then followed your instructions. Now, every thing is okay. Thanks for your patience

Comment: Thanks. I changed the Command Line Tools version from Xcode 11.3 to Xcode 10.3 and it solved my problem.

Comment: Worked for me exactly as described with XCode 12.5, but I needed my Locations  Command Line Tools version to be XCode 12.5 rather than 6.0