# Problems with Cocoapods on Xcode 6.4

Tags: ruby, xcode, cocoapods, homebrew

I'm trying to install and use Cocoapods with Xcode. I've installed already Brew, so I've used this command:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

but it stays there, without response and without asking me for password (that's really strange, because of sudo command).

Maybe I got some problem with Brew Installation or Ruby on my Yosemite iMac?

Comment: can you show us your ruby and gem version?

Comment: Did you recently update XCode? You might need to open XCode and accept the licence agreement.

Comment: @pangpang can't find the gem version... how can I see that? Thanks

Comment: @spickermann Nope... Xcode 7 update is in standby. No agreement to accept...

Comment: @Lum3ll please input  `ruby -v` and `gem --version` in terminal.

Comment: @pangpang Here are the versions:

ruby 2.2.1p85 (2015-02-26 revision 49769) [x86_64-darwin14]

gem 2.4.8

Comment: @Lum3ll I met the same error in the past, there is something wrong with my development environment. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24841392/install-cocoapods-failed-on-mac

Comment: @pangpang I'll try that... thanks for now! :)

Comment: Perfect... all is working now! How can I vote your solution? @pangpang

Comment: @Lum3ll very happy to help you！I post my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I met the same error in the past, there is something wrong with my development environment. I re-install the Command Line Tools follow this [guide](http://www.moncefbelyamani.com/how-to-install-xcode-homebrew-git-rvm-ruby-on-mac/), then everything is ok.

You can get the detail information from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24841392/install-cocoapods-failed-on-mac), hope it can help you.

Comment: Perfect... all solved! Need a vote for my question to get a badge... thanks ;)